# How to get an anonymous instance that extends a class from a field with java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, field, anonymous

I have a class "S" in which I create fields of an anonymous classed derived from class "T":

```
class T {
  public void foo() {}
}

class S {
  T t1 = new T() {};
  T t2 = new T() {};
}
```

I need to iterate through all T fields of an S instance in other to call "foo".
The problem is that I cannot create an instance to pass to Field.get(...) since this is an anonymous class. If I pass a T instance, I get an IllegalArgumentException...

Any chance to make it work?

**EDIT**

Ok I understand now that I should pass a S to Field.get(). However I oversimplified and the situation is a bit more complicated. S is actually an anonymous class:

```
class SM { 
  class S {
    void bar() {...}

    class T {
      public void foo() {}
    }
  }
}

....

SM sm = new SM() {
  S s = new S() {
    T t1 = new T() {};
    T t2 = new T() {};
  }
}
```

I need to access all T fields in S.bar(). Thanks!

**EDIT AGAIN**

pff I need to pass "this" to Field.get(), of course. Thank you all, sorry for that, I'm feeling dumb.

Comment: Could you update your code after edit? What is the meaning of the field s in the anonymous class - and how someone can access it in the current definition?

Comment: So, does it mean you question is already answered?

Comment: yes ! To answer your question, actually there is no need to access the fields from the exterior in my use. A bit more context: I implement a State Machine: SM is StateMachine, S is State, and T is Transition...

Answer (score 1):

When you call field.get(Object) you need to pass an instance on which the call will be made

```
S s = new S();
Class<?> sClass = s.getClass();
Field[] fields = sClass.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field field : fields){
    if(field.getType().equals(T.class)){
        T instance = (T)field.get(s);
        instance.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, first I did not understand that I had to pass an S instance. But I forgot to say something, the code is actually:

Answer (score 0):

Hhmm, don't really see your problem. How about:

```
S s = new S();
Field t1Field = S.class.getDeclaredField("t1");
t1Field.setAccessible(true);
T t1 = (T)t1Field.get(s);
t1.foo();
```